# How do I handle not being scheduled for a job that I was hired for?

Tags: hiring-process, scheduling

I was hired by my college for a tutoring job. I applied expecting to have a weekly schedule, because that is generally what other people who were hired by them get. Instead, they asked me to check in on a weekly basis to see if I had any students. After 3 weeks with no students, I stopped checking.

There is going to be a general meeting next week. They have asked me to attend. I realize I cannot force them to give me hours, so how should I handle this meeting? Should I just straight-up quit, or should I say I will have to quit unless I get weekly hours?

Comment: Are you paid by the potential students needing a tutor or does the college pay you? Have they not been paying you due to not having anyone to tutor?

Comment: @BSMP The college pays. From what I understand, the new policy is not to schedule a tutoring session until 3 students can come.

Comment: Listen first to understand the tone of the general meeting and I would find an avenue to voice your concerns. Seek to understand why and then suggest changes.

Comment: Are you currently getting paid or not?

Comment: @Cronax no I am not

Answer (score 4):

> I realize I cannot force them to give me hours, so how should I handle
>   this meeting?

Go to the meeting and listen to what is said.

If it doesn't come up, then ask if not having a regular schedule of students is typical or not.

And if you conclude that this kind of sporadic schedule doesn't meet your needs, find a new job that does, then leave this one. While looking for a new job, ask specifically during interviews about the kinds of hours you can expect to receive.

Comment: Sometimes just asking is the easiest simplest way to go....